# How to automatically scroll down on a modal via click on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on a page , when clicking on it, a scroll down is done , and if I'm on the bottom of the page when clicking on it, it scrolls up.

```
<style>
    .scroll_button {
        position: fixed;
        right: 35px;
        z-index: 100;
    }
</style>

<div class="scroll_button" style="bottom: 10px;">
    <button id="scroll_id" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span> Click to Scroll</span><br><i id="scroll_icon" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<script>
//scroll up and down

    $(function () {
        $('#scroll_id').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $win = $(window);
            var scrollTarget = $win.height() + $win.scrollTop() + 1 >= $(document).height() ? 0 : $win.scrollTop() + $win.height()
            $("html, body, .modal").animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTarget
            }, 600);

        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a modal in this page and I want to have the same button that scrolls the content of the modal when clicking on that button.

So, I copied the html code the the button and put it to the body of the modal but  the page behind the modal was scrolling not the modal's window .

I have added `.modal` class to the selectors in the script so that modal will be scrolled (I found that in some posts on stackoverflow) but seems to be not working.

Do I miss something in the code ? 
How should I proceed? Thanks

Comment: So you want to automatically scroll the modal on click and not enable scroll on click ? Those are 2 different things.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what you mean, But What I mean is , when click on the button in the modal it scrolls down (if the bottom of the modal is reached, the click on the button scrolls up to the top)

Answer (score 0):

When you copied and pasted the code you also copied the id `scroll_icon`. Id's are unique identifiers that enable you to use CSS or JavaScript to target a specific DOM element. You will need to change the id on your modal and the code associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (e){
  $(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.scroll_id',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $win = $(window);
        var scrollTarget = $win.height() + $win.scrollTop() + 1 >= $(document).height() ? 0 : $win.scrollTop() + $win.height();

       if($(this).parent('.modal').length) {
           var $scrCont = $(".modal")
       }
       else {
           var $scrCont = $("html, body");
       }

       $($scrCont).animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTarget
    }, 600);

   });
});
```

});

You can identify a parent of the button and animate the right component.

If I understand your issue correctly -- https://jsfiddle.net/oerhbwr4/6/

Comment: thanks ..but I don't know why it's not working for me :/ 
by the way, why the scroll button in the modal is scrolled too in the fiddle ?